# No decimals with SASS, possible?

Tags: css, sass, decimal

I use a lot of calc() with percentage values (eg. calc((100vh / 8) + 20px)) in my project. So this results in a lot of decimal values (See image). So is it possible that there are not decimals? So 59.63 would be 60. I'm using SASS.

[image]

Best wishes,
Joeri

Comment: Can you explain why this is even a problem? From a display point-of-view, this is something that doesn't need to be solved. (Also, `calc()` is computed in the browser, not by SASS.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's **not possible** while you are using relative units (%, em, rem, etc). When rendering they are recalculated to pixels and gets decimals values.
About css units you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

But anyway brouser renders blocks with integer sizes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDlbe.png In your case the real size of this block may be 60 to 60 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the round function from SASS :

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#round-instance_method

Comment: This is not doing what I want. It converts 25.5555556% to 26% but still outputs 59.63px